# WildFly deploy: Unable to create EntityManager with SynchronizationType

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, wildfly-8

I am trying to migrate a GlassFish 4.0 webapp to deploy on WildFly 8.1.0 FINAL. The app deploys correctly, but after sendind GET request (e.g. typing localhost:8080/meanful/), strange error occurs:

```
2:57:15,493 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-4) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component SystemDaoImpl for method public abstract boolean com.meanful.service.system.SystemDao.contains(java.lang.String): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create EntityManager with SynchronizationType because PersistenceUnit is configured with resource-local transactions.
```

My persistence.xml looks like this and is fully functional with the same version of EclipseLink on my GlassFish 4 server.

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="mysqlPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/mySQL</jta-data-source>
     <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
        </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The implementation class itself looks like this:

```
@Stateless
public class SystemDaoImpl implements SystemDao {

@PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public boolean contains(String infoKey) {
    return entityManager.find(SystemInfo.class, infoKey) != null;

    }
```

Entity manager is injected. The error is thrown when the program reaches the inside  of contains() method (there is only one line).

The connection is set properly, connection test shows everything is OK.
[image: JTA is enabled]
[image]

Comment: Just guessing, are you using a local-tx-datasource? If yes, maybe you need to use an XA-datasource: `<xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>`

Comment: I've added a screenshot with my Datasource settings. Everything looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes looks all fine to me too.

Comment: I've tried creating non-xa datasource with just com.mysql.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource - to no avail. However in both cases, ping (test connection) works.

Comment: It has probably nothing to do with the datasource. Another guess: You write you are using EclipseLink while WildFly uses Hibernate. Could it be that you have an EclipseLink jar in your deployment that you maybe just need to remove?

Comment: I deployed EclipseLink into modules/system/... and there is EclipseLink defined as a provider in persistence.xml. I tried to run on Hibernate, but the whole application is JEE 7 - JPA specific, which means I am getting errors while using Hibernate.

Comment: WildFly 8 is JEE 7 including JPA provided by Hibernate so I suppose your JEE 7 app should ideally just work and it should not be necessary to use EclipseLink.

Comment: Your advice to switch to Hibernate works. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, good it works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, check for line:

`<resource-root path="jipijapa-eclipselink-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>`

in your *modules/system/layers/base/org/eclipse/persistence/main/module.xml* `<resource>` element.

> jipijapa-eclipselink-1.0.1.Final.jar:
>
> > This library is a collection of utility classes to aid the integration
> >     of EclipseLink into JBossAS7

There should be **two lines** (an integration and eclipselink library) according to:

[JPA Reference Guide - Using EclipseLink](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingEclipseLink)

Answer (score 1):

This Issue is EclipseLink related. EclipseLink 2.5.1. was defined as a provider in persistence.xml. After removing this declaration and letting Hibenate bundled in WildFly do it's work, everything works.

I still haven't found out why this strange error occurs. It looks like EclipseLink thinks transaction management is RESOURCE_LOCAL.

Comment: ... so why did you accept that other answer? Which one is it?